# Combine 100 2D arrays into one 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 100 2D lists a0 to a99, it is easy to convert them into arrays (I verified already):

```
print(np.array(a0).shape)   # (2,150)
print(np.array(a1).shape)   # (5,150)
print(np.array(a2).shape)   # (10, 150)
# the sizes of a0 to a99 vary from (1,150) to (10, 150) only
```

I want to combine these 100 3D arrays into ONE 3D array, for example **combined_array**:

```
print(combined_array.shape)  # (100,10,150)
print(combined_array[0].shape) # (2,150)
print(conbined_array[1].shape) # (5,150)
print(combined_array[2].shape) # (10,150)
```

I use Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays have different shapes on the 0 axis, so you cannot use [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) directly.

You can either use padding or put all arrays in a list. Using padding:

```
import numpy as np

a0 = np.empty((2,150))
a1 = np.empty((5,150))
a2 = np.empty((10,150))

max_shape = [0,0]
for a in [a0, a1, a2]:
    if max_shape[0] < a.shape[0]:
        max_shape[0] = a.shape[0]
    if max_shape[1] < a.shape[1]:
        max_shape[1] = a.shape[1]
arrays = []
for a in [a0, a1, a2]:
    arrays.append(np.pad(a, pad_width=((0, max_shape[0] - a.shape[0]),
                                       (0, max_shape[1] - a.shape[1])),
                         mode='constant'))
stacked_array = np.stack(arrays)
```